# gnuplot pm3d - Font size control for axis in multiplots

Tags: gnuplot

I posted a question previously about plotting multiple 3D surfaces together as a multiplot. I got the solution for that but now I am having issue with controlling the fonts of the graphs.
[The fonts are terrible in multiplot and My settings are not doing anything with them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyDGR.png)
[I don't know how to control these fonts. I tried ztics but it does not change anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjokv.png)

Here is my code:

```
set terminal png size 2000,1600 enhanced transparent
set encoding utf8 #iso_8859_1
set output 'output.png'
set border linewidth 2
set pm3d border lw 2
####Set the Axis and Axis-Labels Formatting####
set format '%g'
set xtics font "Helvetica,26" scale 3 # Font for xtics
set xtics offset 3,-1.5 # Put xtics away from the axis
set ytics font "Helvetica,26" scale 3
set ytics offset 3,0 # Put ytics away from the axis
set ztics font "Helvetica,26" scale 3
set ztics 5 # Difference between numbers on Y-axis
set format z "" # To hide ztics on the left side
set grid # Show gridlines on both axis
set pm3d interpolate 1,1
unset key
###---Plot the Graph###---
splot "plastoquinone-scan-a3-formatted.txt" with pm3d   # For a single plot

#----------------#
#  Set Multiplot #
#----------------#
#set multiplot layout 3,3
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-a1-formatted.txt" with pm3d
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-a3-formatted.txt" with pm3d,
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-b1-formatted.txt" with pm3d,
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-b2-formatted.txt" with pm3d,
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-b3-formatted.txt" with pm3d,
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-c1-formatted.txt" with pm3d,
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-c2-formatted.txt" with pm3d,
#splot "plastoquinone-scan-c3-formatted.txt" with pm3d
```

Please suggest how can I control the settings for fonts in multiplot and how can I control the fonts of the "key" appearing on the right side (circled red in figure).
I am unable to insert the links of the input files due to less reputation :(
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here are the links for input files:
https://github.com/i4hashmi/Scans/blob/master/plastoquinone-scan-a1-formatted.txt

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.... if you want smaller fonts, then simply use a smaller font size than 26. To set the font for the colorbar use `set cbtics`. Or you can change the font globally in the `set terminal` command.

Comment: Thanks user8153... That solved the issue. It is controlled by `cbtics`. Cheers